# How to set Text for EditText with Date Picker in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, android-edittext, android-datepicker

I am new to Kotlin and android app development.

I am following a online course and one of the exercises is picking date to remind a to do item at certain time.

What i did is created EditText and implemented DatePicker. When user clicks date picker is opened and after I select the date, I can not set to text of EditText.

BTW I already checked other related questions and it says check your id to make sure you are referring to non null widget in correct layout file. I double checked it and it is not the problem

Here is the error.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

```
//EditText on layout file
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/calendarEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="Select your date"
    android:focusable="false"
/>

//My Kotlin code
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add)

    //DatePicker is called inside onCreate function
    calendarEditText.setOnClickListener {
        val newFragment = DatePickerFragment()
        newFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "datePicker")
    }
}
// DateSet part of my DatePickerFragment
override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {

    //selected date converted into one string
    val date = "$year/$month/$dayOfMonth"

    //this is where I got the error
    calendarEditText.setText(date)
}
```

Comment: Try to use `findViewById()`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but in Kotlin you dont need findViewById() and it is tested already in previous lines by directly calling the ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me calendarEditText is null because you call it in a DatePickerFragment, so you are in a different context.

In your onDataSet, update edittext like that :

```
((MyActivity) activity).setEdt(date);
```

and in your activity, something like that :

```
public setEdt(date: String): void {
calendarEditText.setText(date)
}
```

or follow this [tuto](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/android-datepicker-kotlin-example/) to avoid fragment

Answer (score 0):

birthdate.setOnClickListener {

```
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
            this, { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

                val c1 = Calendar.getInstance()
                c1.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
                var strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(c1.time)
                birthdate.setText(strDate)
            }, year, month, day
        )
        datePickerDialog.show()
    }

  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/birthdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).